# How to reload func generate RSA key-pairs in OpenSSL 3.0 provider?

Tags: c, openssl

Question for OpenSSL3.0.

I had created my provider for my security SDK like wolfProvider. I hadn't found the interface to generate RSA key pair by my SDK cross OpenSSL3.0. In OpenSSL1.1, I used the engine and reload RSA_pmeth to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear from your question, but I think you are asking how to implement RSA key generation within an OpenSSL 3.0 provider.

To do this, the provider must supply an RSA KEYMGMT implementation. Specifically it should implement the various "gen" functions described here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/provider-keymgmt.html

There are further details on the specific parameters required for RSA on this page:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-RSA.html

That same page also shows an example at the end of how an application uses the EVP APIs to generate an RSA key.